# i am trying to access .ini file where stored the db information for powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-conversion

When I run this code I get default value as "sorry" instead of original value.
Here is my code:

```
sle_dbms.text = ProfileString( "C:\database.ini" , &
                                "DBMS" , "DBMS" , "Sorry" )
sle_database.text = ProfileString( "C:\database.ini" , &
                                "DBMS" , "ServerName" , "Sorry" )
sle_name.text = ProfileString( "C:\database.ini" , &
                               "DBMS" , "LogId" , "Sorry" )
```

Please help me to fix this query...

Comment: Which default value is 'sorry'?  Your example is looking at three separate values.

Comment: May we please see the relevant data from your .ini file please?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide enough information to answer conclusively. Rather than leave this unanswered, will provide extra information so that it can be answered and help others with same challenge.

**Scenario 1**

INI file named c:\database.ini does not exist

**Result**:

All three calls to the ProfileString function return the default 'Sorry' because there was no ini file

**Scenario 2**:

INI File exists with the contents like:

```
[DBMS]
DBMS=Hello
DSN=World
ServerName=Matrix
LoginId=jdoe
DebugLevel=1
```

**Result**: Third ProfileString returns default because 'LogId' not in INI file

```
// These find respective file, section, key and therefore return the ini value 
ProfileString("C:\database.ini", "DBMS", "DBMS"  "Sorry") will return 'Hello'
ProfileString("C:\database.ini", "DBMS", "ServerName", "Sorry") will return 'Matrix'

// File & section found but key 'LoginId' was misspelled so returns default 'Sorry'
ProfileString( "C:\database.ini","DBMS", "LogUserId", "Sorry") will return 'Sorry'
```